# Floating zero Division Error in newtons method code

Tags: python

My code for newtons method is displaying divide by zero error. Why am I getting this?

```html
from math import *
x = 2
for iteration in range(1,1001):
    N0 = .00003
    NI =1000
    b =.12
    xnew = x - ((N0*exp((log1p(NI/N0))*(1-exp(-b*x))))-1)/(b*N0*exp((log1p(NI/N0))*(1-exp(-b*x))-b*x)) # the Newton-Raphson's formula
    if abs(xnew - x) < 0.000001:
        break
    x = xnew
print('The root : %0.5f' % xnew)
print('The number of iterations : %d' % iteration)
```

w

Comment: You should subdivide the formulas with temporary variables over multiple lines to find the precise place where the error happens and which formula part results in `0`.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger and seeing which iteration the loop fails on?  An alternative could be wrapping the assignment of `xnew` in a try/catch and logging the calculations in the denominator and seeing if something appears off.  It's not obvious to spot the error just by looking at your code.

Comment: Use just `%.5f`: the zero is a field width (ignored because it is of course too small).